# Error with syntax in SPSS for MANCOVA

Tags: syntax, spss

I am trying to run a MANCOVA. 
Dependent variables: F_enjoy F_curios F_compli F_recogn F_social
Independent variable: Group4 (four different levels)
Covariates:P_progress P_obscomp P_socfdbk P_psystate

```
    MANOVA F_enjoy F_curios F_compli F_recogn F_social BY Group4 (1,4)
    WITH P_progress P_obscomp P_socfdbk P_psystate/
      PRINT=CELLINFO (MEANS)
      HOMOGENEITY (ALL)
      ERROR(COR)
      SIGNIF(UNIV, MULTIV)/
  OMEAN=VARIABLES (F_enjoy, F_curios, F_compli, F_recogn, F_social) 
  TABLES (Group4) /plot=normal
  PARAMETERS (ESTIM)/
  PMEANS/
  DESIGN.
```

When I try to run this, I keep getting this error message: 1 MANOVA A PLOT specification is incorrect. I do not see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you messed up the syntax by editing it. I would encourage to write the syntax yourself, but take a good look at the order of commands and the specification in the Command Syntax Reference (in the help menu). I guess this should work:

```
MANOVA F_enjoy F_curios F_compli F_recogn F_social BY Group4 (1,4)
   WITH P_progress P_obscomp P_socfdbk P_psystate
  /PRINT=CELLINFO(MEANS) HOMOGENEITY(ALL)
         ERROR(COR) SIGNIF(UNIV, MULTIV) PARAMETERS(ESTIM)
  /OMEANS=VARIABLES (F_enjoy, F_curios, F_compli, F_recogn, F_social) 
  /PMEANS=TABLES(Group4) 
  /plot=normal
  /DESIGN.
```

There is actually a lot of excess syntax here. I think the following would yield the same results, because most of the specifications are default:

```
MANOVA F_enjoy F_curios F_compli F_recogn F_social BY Group4 (1,4)
   WITH P_progress P_obscomp P_socfdbk P_psystate
  /OMEANS=VARIABLES (F_enjoy, F_curios, F_compli, F_recogn, F_social) 
  /PMEANS=TABLES(Group4) 
  /plot=normal.
```

I don't have comparable data so I am not completely sure, but just try it and try to figure out how syntax works! I can be of great help in accurately estimating your models.

Answer (score -2):

TITLE 'MANCOVA-2 DEP VARS AND 2 COVS'.
DATA LIST FREE/GPID Y1 Y2 X1 X2.
BEGIN DATA.
Compression Test    42  39  46  85
Compression Test    44  33  45  78
Compression Test    41  38  37  75
Compression Test    48  33  54  87
Compression Test    43  44  36  80
Compression Test    45  47  36  83
Compression Test    46  40  39  79
Compression Test    45  43  33  76
Compression Test    42  47  36  83
Hammer Test 47  43  50  93
Hammer Test 40  39  41  80
Hammer Test 33  38  28  66
Hammer Test 50  44  56  100
Hammer Test 33  40  26  66
Hammer Test 33  42  24  66
Hammer Test 33  40  26  66
Hammer Test 27  38  15  53
Hammer Test 37  42  31  73
END DATA.
LIST.
MANOVA Y1 Y2 X1 X2 BY GPID(1,2)/
ANALYSIS Y1 Y2 WITH X1 X2/
PRINT=PMEANS/
DESIGN/
ANALYSIS=Y1 Y2/
DESIGN=X1 + X2, GPID, X1 BY GPID + X2 BY GPID/.

Comment: is this supposed to be an answer to the question? what is this?